# How many numbers that you can print in 1 second

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I want to print n numbers to `stdout` with a maximum time limit of 1 second and n can be up to 100000.

I tried to concatenate the output as a string and then stream this to `cout` but it did not work.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    int n = 100000;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    cout<<i<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

It prints until 12769 and then gives a runtime error:

[image: 1]

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please, provide us with the code, the output of your test-run - And we can help.

Comment: @HarshSingh  a note only; because you're new!  We all can forget to add code/and it sometimes can be difficult to know exactly what and what not to include in a question, even the most trivial things can be forgotten. Don't worry! We all do wrongs here n there. //Best of luck!

Comment: Sorry, I did not know about it. However, I have added the code snippet.

Comment: Also please add the exact error message that you get.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I did that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in 1 second"? A low powered CPU might print less numbers than a fast one

Comment: How  do you want to limit the run time? Do you want to print one number per 1/n seconds?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I think OP wants to see whether or not 100000 numbers can be printed in 1 second, and if not how many numbers will print before the time limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, it appears to me that you are using `ideone.com` to compile and run your code. Per the [FAQ](https://ideone.com/faq):

> What is the size limit for the source code, input and output?
> 64 kB.

Your output exceeds the size limit when it reaches the 5th digit of the number 12774. Try compiling and running it on your local machine instead.

As a side note, you said in your question that the code is meant to have a maximum running time of 1 second, but you have not implemented this in the code. Therefore you will not get the result you expect even if you fix the runtime error.